# Java charset - Como ler corretamente do System.in?

Tags: java, socket, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, console

Estou criando um aplicativo para trocar mensagens entre computadores utilizando Sockets, através do cmd ou terminal (quero que rode em linux e windows, aplicação de console).

Mas estou com problema quanto a codificação. Quando leio um entrada através do System.in, no console do Windows 7, a saída é bugada. Com o seguinte código:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(s.nextLine());
```

Os caracteres acentuados ou especiais não são exibidos corretamente.

Estou utilizando o seguindo código para transmitir mensagens:

```
Main.CHARSET = "UTF-8"

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in,Main.CHARSET);
BufferedWriter saida = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream()),Main.CHARSET)));
saida.write(nick + " conectado!");
saida.flush();
while (teclado.hasNextLine()) {
    saida.write(nick +": "+ s);
    saida.flush();
}
```

E para receber:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servidor,Main.CHARSET)));
String s;
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

A questão é, como ler corretamente do console e transmitir de modo que o o outro usuário receba e seja capaz de visualizar em seu console?

Comment: Está usando algum IDE? Lembro que tive problemas para exibir caracteres especiais no console do NetBeans, fiquei dias procurando solução e nada. Até que descobri que a codificação mostrada no console nao é Utf-8 e por isso ficava bugado.

Comment: @renan, uso o Netbeans e dependendo do charset que esolho para o Scanner, ele não exibe, mas estou testando a aplicação no console do windows 7 mesmo. Não sei se o cmd tem sua codificação de entrada, e quando utilizamos o Scanner no System.in com algum charset, ele apenas faz algo do tipo: 
    'á em cp1252, byte = 160 -> tenta ler o mesmo byte = 160 em utf-8'